# Cube root of a negative number in Python

Tags: python, canopy

```
x = int(raw_input("enter number:"))
ans = 0
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans+1
if ans**3 != abs(x):
    print("Not a perfect cube")
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print(str(ans)+'  '+'is cube root of'+str(x))
```

This is the correct code..

But when i first tried i left out    `if x<0:   ans=-ans`

And got  **-27**   as output

Why am i getting -27, if i don't put ans=-ans, shouldn't i get ans itself as answer..

I'm starting fresh in programming through an online course, sorry for being an ultra n00b..

Thanks

Comment: "ans=-ans**" this syntax doesn't exist

Comment: presumably the asterisks at the end of that line, and the two at the beginning of the previous line, are meant to be markup that make the lines bold, and aren't actually part of the code.

Comment: 3 is not the cube root of -27.

Comment: There is an error in the code: it takes the absolute value of `x`, so inputting `-27` gives you the same result as `27`.

Comment: Nothing in that code can possibly produce the the output `Out -27` nor `Out is cube root of -27`. Please copy-paste an actual program that demonstrates the error you were seeing.

Comment: Sorry , the "Out" actually mean't nothing, i.e. if i enter the value in line  In[1]  i get the answer -27 in line Out[1].. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: In that case, what is the actual output of the program when you run it,  what is your expected output, and what is your question? For completeness' sake, when I run your program, with the two mentioned lines deleted, I get `3  is cube root of-27`.

Comment: @unutbu Ok it should show the abs value if there is an error, but the output i am getting is -27..???

Comment: Got it , it was totally my noobness, i simply entered -27 and got -27 in return, instead of running the code again.. Oh man i feel stupid..Thanks everyone.. Much appreciated...

Comment: Aravind edited his question

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))

for ans in range(0, abs(x) + 1):
    if ans ** 3 == abs(x):
        break
if ans ** 3 != abs(x):
    print x, 'is not a perfect cube!'
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print 'Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans)
```